# Looking for help with reasoning about a function defined on congruence relations

Tags: inequality, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification, congruence-relations

Let:

- $T_{p,r}(n,x)$ be the count of integer $i$ such that:

> - $p$ is an odd prime
> - $n,r<p,x$ are integers
> - $n - x \le i < n$
> - $i \equiv r \pmod {p}$
> - for all prime $q > 2$ where $i \equiv r \pmod {q}$, it follows that $p \le q$

Does it now follow that for any odd prime $p$, any integers $r, n, x$:

$$T_{p,1}(0,x) \ge T_{p,r}(n,x) \ge T_{p,0}(0,x)$$

I am finding it difficult to prove that this is the case in light of the 5th bullet point which is my attempt to generalize the concept of [least prime factor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html) to [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Am I wrong in my assumption?

---

**Edit:**  Attempting an argument for $T_{p,1}(0,x) \ge T_{p,r}(n,x)$ where $r=1$:

It occurs to me that this special case of my assumption is straight forward to show:

(1)  Assume it is not true so that there exists $p,n,x$ such that:

$$T_{p,1}(0,x) < T_{p,1}(n,x)$$

(2)  Let:

- $S_{0,x,q}$ be the set of integers $i$ where $-x \le i < 0$ and there exists a minimal prime $q$ such that $q < p$ and $i \equiv 1 \pmod q$ and $i \equiv 1 \pmod p$
- $S_{n,x,q}$ be the set of integers $j$ where $n-x \le j < n$ and there exists a prime $q$ such that $q < p$ and $j \equiv 1 \pmod q$ and $j \equiv 1 \pmod p$
- $|S_{0,x,q}|$ be the count of elements in $S_{0,x,q}$ and $|S_{n,x,q}|$ be the count of elements in $S_{n,x,q}$

(3) There must exist at least one $q$ where $m=|S_{0,x,q}| > |S_{n,x,q}|$

(4) But then, $x \ge mpq+1$  Otherwise, it would be impossible for $m$ such elements to exist.

(5) It follows $n-x, n-x+1, n-x+2, \dots, n-x+mpq$ forms a [complete residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system) modulo $n-x+mpq+1$

(6) But then $|S_{n,x,q}| \ge m$ which contradicts step(3).

(7) So, we can reject our assumption at step(1).

---

**Edit 2:** Attempting an argument for $T_{p,1}(0,x) \ge T_{p,r}(n,x)$ where $r>1$:

(1)  Assume it is not true so that there exists $p,n,x$ such that:

$$T_{p,1}(0,x) < T_{p,1}(n,x)$$

(2)  From the argument above, we can assume that $x \ge pqm+1$ and $x < pqm+r$.  Otherwise, the same argument applies.

(3)  We can assume that:

$$\sum_{\text{all }q}|S_{0,x,q}| = \sum_{\text{all }q}|S_{n,x,q}|+1$$

- Assume that $\sum\limits_{\text{all }q}|S_{0,x,q}| > \sum\limits_{\text{all }q}|S_{n,x,q}|+1$
- Then, there exists primes $q_1, q_2$ such that $q_1p +1 < q_1p + p +1 \le x < q_1p + r$
- But this is impossible since by assumption $r < p$

(4) Let $U_{p,r}(n,x)$ be the count of integers $i$ where $n-x \le i < n$ and $i \equiv r \pmod p$ so that:

$$T_{p,r}(n,x) = U_{p,r}(n,x) - \sum_{\text{all }q}|S_{n,x,q}|$$

(5) It follows from step(1) that $U_{p,1}(0,x) = mpq$ while $U_{p,r}(n,x) = mpq-1$

(6) Combining step(5) and step(3):

$$T_{p,1}(0,x) = U_{p,r}(n,x)+1 - \sum\limits_{\text{all }q}|S_{n,x,q}|-1 = T_{p,r}(n,x)$$

(7) This contradicts step (1) so we can reject our assumption in step(1).

Comment: There are a few small issues. First, your definition of $T_{p,r}(n,x)$. You don't state it explicitly, but it only really makes sense if $r \ge 0$. Also, if $x \le 0$, then there are no $i$ in the range. Thus, I suggest your second bullet point should be something like "$n, 0 \le r \lt p, x \ge 1$ are integers" instead. Another issue is with your $(1)$ in your **Edit 2** section. It should state you're assuming an $r$ exists, plus the line below should use $r$ on the right, i.e., be $T_{p,1}(0,x) \lt T_{p,r}(n,x)$. It seems you copied & pasted from your **Edit** part but forgot to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note with your definition of $T_{p,r}(n,x)$, your fourth & fifth bullet points combined basically state you're looking for where the least odd prime factor (I'm calling call it $\operatorname{lopf}$ for simplicity) of $r + (-i)$ is $p$.

Your conjecture is equivalent to all of the following $3$ inequalities being true:

$$T_{p,1}(0,x) \ge T_{p,r}(n,x) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$T_{p,r}(n,x) \ge T_{p,0}(0,x) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$T_{p,1}(0,x) \ge T_{p,0}(0,x) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Of course, if the first $2$ are true, then so is the third one. However, a counter-example to \eqref{eq1A} is $T_{3,1}(0,1) = 0$, but $T_{3,1}(5,1) = 1$. Also, a counter-example to \eqref{eq2A} is $T_{5,0}(16,5) = 0$ (since with $q = 3$, then $q \mid 15$ and $q \lt p$, so $15$ is excluded), but $T_{5,0}(0,5) = 1$. Nonetheless, \eqref{eq3A} is always true, as I show later.

---

Regarding your **Edit** attempt to prove $T_{p,1}(0,x) \ge T_{p,r}(n,x)$ where $r = 1$, this is a special case of \eqref{eq1A}, and I already gave a counter-example with $r = 1$, i.e., with $p = 3$, $x = 1$ and $n = 5$. In your attempted proof by contradiction, with your $(3)$, you seem to be assuming that if the number of integers where the $\operatorname{lopf}$ is $p$ in one range is greater than in a second range, the second range must have at least one prime $q \lt p$ (you don't state your $q$ must be odd, but it only makes sense since your $T_{p,r}(n,x)$ definition only worries about odd prime factors) where the number of values with $\operatorname{lopf}$ being $q$ is greater than that in the first range. However, as my example shows, this is not always the case. For one thing, if $p = 3$, there is not even any such $q \lt p$. However, even if $p \gt 3$, then it's still not necessarily true, e.g., with $T_{5,1}(0,1) = 0$ and $T_{5,1}(7,1) = 1$.

Your $(4)$ states $x \ge mpq+1$. However, with some $q \lt p$, have $i = -x = -pq + 1$. Then $i \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $i \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$, so $m = 1$. However, $x = pq - 1$. The correct statement to make is actually $x \ge mpq - 1$.

This, of course, affects your $(5)$. Also, you state it forms a complete residue system modulo $n - x + mpq + 1$. However, for example if $n = 0$ and $x = mpq + 1$, this modulo expression is $0$. I believe you meant to state it is for modulo $mpq + 1$ instead. Nonetheless, a minor point is you actually want to instead state the range of integers contains a complete residue system modulo $mpq$, to then try to conclude your $(6)$. However, even then, there's a potential complication if any of those values which have a factor of $pq$ also have an odd prime factor smaller than $q$.

With your **Edit 2** attempt to prove $T_{p,1}(0,x) \ge T_{p,r}(n,x)$ where $r \gt 1$, a specific counter-example is $T_{3,1}(0,1) = 0$ and $T_{3,2}(6,1) = 1$. Since the rest of your argument is based on the faulty logic and results of the first edit proof, this proof likewise is not reliable.

---

To prove \eqref{eq3A}, first here is a definition of the $\operatorname{lopf}$ function, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all primes:

$$\operatorname{lopf}(m) = \begin{cases}
1 & m = \pm 2^j, j \in \mathbb{Z}, j \ge 0 \\
\min\{q : q \mid m, \, q \in \mathbb{P}, \, q \gt 2 \} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, your $T_{p,r}(n,x)$ can be defined as

$$T_{p,r}(n,x) = \left|\{i : \operatorname{lopf}(r - i) = p, \, n - x \le i \lt n \}\right| \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

As $x$ increases starting from $1$, both sides of \eqref{eq3A} stay at $0$ until $x$ gets to the first value where $\operatorname{lopf}(x + 1) = \operatorname{lopf}(-x - 1) = p$. In that case, since $-x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, then $T_{p,1}(0,x) = 1$, but $T_{p,0}(0,x) = 0$ still. However, when $x$ increases by $1$ more, then $\operatorname{lopf}(x) = p$, so $T_{p,0}(0,x) = 1$, which means both sides are equal. This continues until the next larger $x$ where $\operatorname{lopf}(x + 1) = p$, with the pattern repeating, i.e., the left side becomes $1$ greater then, but becomes equal with the next larger $x$. In general, whenever $\operatorname{lopf}(x + 1) = p$, then $T_{p,1}(0,x) = T_{p,0}(0,x) + 1$ and, otherwise, $T_{p,1}(0,x) = T_{p,0}(0,x)$.